# How to list categorized items in SharePoint (new at SP)

Tags: sharepoint

I am beginner at Sharepoint and i want to make a small application on it.

I have 3 lists.

- CarFeatures
- Cars
- FeatureType

Here is my data structure

FeatureType:

GearType, Speed, Color,CoolingSystem are my columns.But here i have more columns called  AirCond, Radiator.  CoolingSystem is Parent of these 2 columns.

In CarFeatures :

Title and FeatureType are my columns. I add items here using FeatureType.

In Car :

carName and lookuped FeaturesOfCar are my columns.

So, I want to add items to Car with features. You know, while adding a new item, a window opens and lists your options there. **In this window i want 2 listboxes. one of it should hold FeturesType and when i select one of its, item it should list that FeatureType items' subitems from CarFeatures.** (kind of categorize selecting ) So this way, i'll have flexible system. Coz i wanna use it another places. It must be editable and easy to use.

I hope I am clear.

Comment: Are you aware of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ ? That might get you a good answer to this type of question.

Comment: I am new here too. I'll check thank you @glenatron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem codeless.

In infopath, i add an action to first dropdown list that saves the selected value to a textbox.

And secondly i add "filter data" to second dropdown list.This filter's first condition ist "Title not blank" and second one is "selected item's parentId = featureTypeId".We already holding parentId in textbox. So "selected item's parentId = textBoxField" And finally it solved.